# How to close other windows when the main window is closed in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to close all other windows opened by the main window when the main window is closed.

Please find below the min. code that I was testing:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

import sys


class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    """
    This "window" is a QWidget. If it has no parent, it
    will appear as a free-floating window as we want.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Push for Window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    def show_new_window(self, checked):
        self.w = AnotherWindow()
        self.w.show()

    def close_another_window(self):
        if self.w:
            self.w.close()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = MainWindow()
app.aboutToQuit.connect(w.close_another_window)
w.show()
app.exec()
```

As shown above I tried using the `aboutToQuit` option of the `QApplication`, but it only gets called when the another window also is closed.

I want to close the another window automaticaly when the mainwindow is closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement the [`closeEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent):

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    w = None
    # ...
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.w:
            self.w.close()
```

Note that you can also use [`QApplication.closeAllWindows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#closeAllWindows) to close *any* top level window, even without having any direct reference, but if any of those windows ignores the `closeEvent()` the function will stop trying to close the remaining.

To avoid that, you can cycle all windows using [`QApplication.topLevelWidgets()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets); windows ignoring the `closeEvent` will still keep themselves open, but *all* the others will be closed:

```
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        for window in QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
            window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use signals:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class AnotherWindow(QWidget, close_signal):
    """
    This "window" is a QWidget. If it has no parent, it
    will appear as a free-floating window as we want.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.close_signal = close_signal
        self.close_signal.connect(self.close_me)  # connect handler to signal
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    
    def close_me(self):
        # handler for signal    
        self.close()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    close_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Push for Window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    def show_new_window(self, checked):
        self.w = AnotherWindow(self.close_signal)
        self.w.show()

    def close_another_window(self):
        self.close_signal.emit()  # fire signal to close other windows
```

This mechanism allows to close another window even without closing the main window.

(I used signals for other purposes, hope this works as well)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
   QApplication.closeAllWindows()
   event.accept()
```

with QApplication.closeAllWindows() will close every open window

Answer (score 0):

try my method to close all windows from main window.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, 
QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QMessageBox

from PyQt5.QtGui import QCloseEvent

import sys


class AnotherWindow(QWidget):

      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          layout = QVBoxLayout()
          self.label = QLabel("Another Window")
          layout.addWidget(self.label)
          self.setLayout(layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.button = QPushButton("Push for Window")
          self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
          self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

      def show_new_window(self, checked):
          self.w = AnotherWindow()
          self.w.show()

      def close_all_windows(self):
          win_list = QApplication.allWindows()
          for w in win_list:
              w.close()

      def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent) -> None:
          close = QMessageBox()
          close.setText("voulez vous vraiment quitter l'application ?")
          close.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel)
          close = close.exec()

          if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
             event.accept()
             self.close_all_windows()
          else:
             event.ignore()


 if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: How does it relate to other answers?