# How to close other windows (secondary windows) when the main window is closed in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm quite new to pyqt. I want to close the other windows (secondary windows) automatically when the main window is closed in pyqt5. Following up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70081691/how-to-close-other-windows-when-the-main-window-is-closed-in-pyqt5), the `closeEvent` method was not able to close the secondary windows in the case of the below min. reproducible code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    """
    This "window" is a QWidget. If it has no parent, it
    will appear as a free-floating window as we want.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Ui_MainWindow(QtCore.QObject):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.w = None

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(222, 169)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.pbConnect = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)

        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")

        self.pbConnect.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.pbConnect.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.pbConnect.setDefault(False)
        self.pbConnect.setObjectName("pbConnect")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pbConnect, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

    def callControl(self):
        self.pbConnect.clicked.connect(self.pbConnect_clicked)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pbConnect.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect Device"))

    def pbConnect_clicked(self):
        self.w = AnotherWindow()
        self.w.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.w:
            self.w.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.callControl()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What am I missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Use parent paradigm to force to kill children of parent when parent is killed.

Comment: The problem is that `Ui_MainWindow`, is a basic QObject, implementing `closeEvent` is useless if done like this: to override methods, you must inherit from the class that implements them. I really don't know why you're trying to inherit from QObject, as it's useless for this purpose, but one thing is certain: you're editing a pyuic generated file, which is considered a *bad* practice, mostly because it leds people to try to implement things they don't understand yet. Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @Kaz that has nothing to do with the issue, and Qt already provides such mechanism due to its structure.

Comment: @musicamante Yes [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544780/qtdesigner-changes-will-be-lost-after-redesign-user-interface) answers my question, thanks for the advice. Will definitely follow the official guidelines.